# AWS ECS task definition : Why is my task definitions are active?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm currently running a ec2 instance with no load balancer

intended to run single instance with no scaling

---

I have only one task running but all three tasks are Active

[image]

[image]

I want to know why my all of my task definitions are activated

is it intended or just a default state?

for a backup when latest version of task crushes? or is it for quick scaling?

I can't find a clue for it Doc : [Run a standalone task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTIVE` simply means that you can run a task using the given version. It does not mean that the version is actually running. To make old versions `INACTIVE` (i.e. not usable) you have to [deregister](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deregister-task-definition.html) it.

Comment: so it's like git versions?